# How to JOIN two tables and map three columns

Tags: mysql

2 tables table1 and table 2; requirement is to map two columns in table1 from table 2

```
SELECT , t2.people_names, t2.peoples_names
FROM ( table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.people_ids=t1.people1 )
```

If I add in the FROM statement and AND, in order to map column people2, I get an error.

```
    FROM (table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.people_ids=t1.people1 AND 
   t2.people_ids=t1.people2 )​
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the `people_names` table two times.

```
SELECT t1.people1, tnames1.peoples_names, t1.people2, tnames2.peoples_names
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 tnames1 ON tnames1.people_ids = t1.people1
               JOIN table2 tnames2 ON tnames2.people_ids = t1.people2
```

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow too. If this was useful, consider marking this answer as accepted :)